# Make a budget alert when forcasted is reached

Tags: azure, alert, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, cost-management

I have made a budget in ARM template, where I have two alert under notifications. as default the "ThresholdType" is a "actual" and if i try to change it to forecasted it gives me the error "Value must be one of the following values: "Actual""

The idea is to trigger an alert when the forcasted budget is reached. You can do this in the portal, but is it somehow possible to do this programmatically?

```html
{
                            "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('budgetName')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "timePeriod": {
                                    "startDate": "[parameters('startDate')]",
                                    "endDate": "[parameters('endDate')]"
                                },
                                "timeGrain": "[parameters('timeGrain')]",
                                "amount": "[parameters('amount')]",
                                "category": "Cost",
                                "notifications": {
                                    "NotificationForExceededBudget1": {
                                        "enabled": true,
                                        "operator": "GreaterThan",
                                        "threshold": "[parameters('firstThreshold')]",
                                        "contactEmails": "[parameters('ErrorEmailReceivers')]",
                                        "contactRoles": "[parameters('contactRoles')]",
                                        "contactGroups": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups',variables('WarnAGName'))]"
                                    },
                                    "NotificationForExceededBudget2": {
                                        "enabled": true,
                                        "operator": "GreaterThan",
                                        "threshold": "[parameters('secondThreshold')]",
                                        "contactEmails": "[parameters('WarningEmailReceivers')]",
                                        "contactRoles": "[parameters('contactRoles')]",
                                        "contactGroups": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups',variables('WarnAGName'))]"
                                    }
                                },
                                "filter": {
                                    "and": [
                                        {
                                            "dimensions": {
                                                "name": "ResourceGroupName",
                                                "operator": "In",
                                                "values": "[parameters('resourceGroupFilterValues')]"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "dimensions": {
                                                "name": "MeterCategory",
                                                "operator": "In",
                                                "values": "[parameters('meterCategoryFilterValues')]"
                                            }
                                        }

                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  the below ARM template to create forecasted alerts. we have tested the below template in our local environment & it is working fine.

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "budgetName": {
            "defaultValue": "MyBudget",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Budget. It should be unique within a resource group."
            }
        },
        "amount": {
            "defaultValue": "1000",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The total amount of cost or usage to track with the budget"
            }
        },
        "timeGrain": {
            "defaultValue": "Monthly",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Monthly",
                "Quarterly",
                "Annually"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The time covered by a budget. Tracking of the amount will be reset based on the time grain."
            }
        },
        "startDate": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The start date must be first of the month in YYYY-MM-DD format. Future start date should not be more than three months. Past start date should be selected within the timegrain preiod."
            }
        },
        "endDate": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The end date for the budget in YYYY-MM-DD format. If not provided, we default this to 10 years from the start date."
            }
        },
        "firstThreshold": {
            "defaultValue": "90",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Threshold value associated with a notification. Notification is sent when the cost exceeded the threshold. It is always percent and has to be between 0 and 1000."
            }
        },
        "secondThreshold": {
            "defaultValue": "110",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Threshold value associated with a notification. Notification is sent when the cost exceeded the threshold. It is always percent and has to be between 0 and 1000."
            }
        },
        "contactRoles": {
            "defaultValue": [
                "Owner",
                "Contributor",
                "Reader"
            ],
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of contact roles to send the budget notification to when the threshold is exceeded."
            }
        },
        "contactEmails": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of email addresses to send the budget notification to when the threshold is exceeded."
            }
        },
        "contactGroups": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of action groups to send the budget notification to when the threshold is exceeded. It accepts array of strings."
            }
        },
        "resourceGroupFilterValues": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The set of values for the first filter"
            }
        },
        "meterCategoryFilterValues": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The set of values for the second filter"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('budgetName')]",
            "properties": {
                "timePeriod": {
                    "startDate": "[parameters('startDate')]",
                    "endDate": "[parameters('endDate')]"
                },
                "timeGrain": "[parameters('timeGrain')]",
                "amount": "[parameters('amount')]",
                "category": "Cost",
                "notifications": {
                    "NotificationForExceededBudget1": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "operator": "GreaterThan",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('firstThreshold')]",
                        "thresholdType": "Actual",
                        "contactEmails": "[parameters('contactEmails')]",
                        "contactRoles": "[parameters('contactRoles')]",
                        "contactGroups": "[parameters('contactGroups')]"
                    },
                    "NotificationForExceededBudget2": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "operator": "GreaterThan",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('secondThreshold')]",
                        "thresholdType": "Forecasted",
                        "contactEmails": "[parameters('contactEmails')]",
                        "contactRoles": "[parameters('contactRoles')]",
                        "contactGroups": "[parameters('contactGroups')]"
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "dimensions": {
                                "name": "ResourceGroupName",
                                "operator": "In",
                                "values": "[parameters('resourceGroupFilterValues')]"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "dimensions": {
                                "name": "MeterCategory",
                                "operator": "In",
                                "values": "[parameters('meterCategoryFilterValues')]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]